# Dynamic input value related to another values

Tags: vue.js

I would like to make the value `****here****`of the input `id="inputWorkload"` dynamic and related to the value of inputDuration (newTask.duration * 2 )

How to do it with Vue js?

```html
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputDuration">Duration (H)</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="inputDuration" min="4" step="4" type="number" v-model="newTask.duration">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputWorkload">Workload</label>
        <input disabled class="form-control" id="inputWorkload" value="****here****">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You will need to use JavaScript for this - an on change event for `inputDuration` which updates the value of `inputWorkload`

Comment: Dont forget that `disabled` input will not be carried on in the from submission.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention Vue js

Answer (score 0):

Add an on change event to the duration:

`<input class="form-control" id="inputDuration" min="4" step="4" type="number" v-model="newTask.duration" onchange="myFunction()">`

Then write some JavaScript which gets the value of the duration on change and updates the workload value based on that.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var inputDurationValue = document.getElementById("inputDuration").value;
  document.getElementById("inputWorkload") = inputDurationValue;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you but what if i'm using Vuejs ?

Comment: Wellm if you have `newTask.duration` in your v-model, is it as simple as doing `value={{newTask.duration}}`? I don't know Vue.js, sorry. I'd try that though.

Answer (score -1):

With a watcher. Something like this.

```
data: {
    //define your #inputWorkload variable , let's say "workload"
},

watch: {
    newTask: {
        handler(val){
            this.workload = val.duration * 2;
       },
       deep: true
    },
 }
```

```
// in your template

<input disabled class="form-control" id="inputWorkload"  :value="workload">
```

Comment: No need for a watcher. A computed property is what you're after: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties